# Flutter: weird RangeError (index is within expected range)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have recently migrated my app to Flutter 2 with null safety and I encountered weird error. I have following function which I use to convert *CameraImage* (YUV) into RGB image, which worked flawlessly before going from Flutter 1.26 to 2.3 and migrating. Afterwards, it started to complain about *RangeError (index): Index out of range*, which I do not understand and error description is not helpful.

```
static imageLib.Image convertYUV420ToImage(CameraImage cameraImage) {

   final int width = cameraImage.width;
   final int height = cameraImage.height;

   final int uvRowStride = cameraImage.planes[1].bytesPerRow;
   final int? uvPixelStride = cameraImage.planes[1].bytesPerPixel;

   final image = imageLib.Image(width, height);
   for (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
     for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
       final int uvIndex =
           uvPixelStride! * (w / 2).floor() + uvRowStride * (h / 2).floor();
       final int index = h * width + w;

       print("index $index and $uvIndex");
       final y = cameraImage.planes[0].bytes[index];
       final u = cameraImage.planes[1].bytes[uvIndex];
       final v = cameraImage.planes[2].bytes[uvIndex];

       image.data[index] = ImageUtils.yuv2rgb(y, u, v);
     }
   }
   return image;
 }
```

Output is

```
...
I/flutter (19516): index 344169 and 172088
I/flutter (19516): index 344889 and 172088
I/flutter (19516): index 10 and 10
E/flutter (19516): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(1138)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (19516): RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 345600: 10
E/flutter (19516): #0      _Uint8ArrayView.[] (dart:typed_data-patch/typed_data_patch.dart:4070:7)
E/flutter (19516): #1      ImageUtils.convertYUV420ToImage (package:anh_flutter/recognition/ImageUtils.dart:42:46)
E/flutter (19516): #2      ImageUtils.convertCameraImage (package:anh_flutter/recognition/ImageUtils.dart:13:14)
E/flutter (19516): #3      IsolateUtils.entryPoint (package:anh_flutter/recognition/IsolateUtils.dart:47:30)
```

Which hardly makes any sense as **10** is less than **345600**. I also checked that *cameraImage.planes[0].bytes.length* is indeed **345600** as expected.

Pls could anyone help me understanding what might be wrong here?

Comment: Hey try not to use  2.3 - it is not stable. try 2.2 or 2.5.

Comment: please try: directly access, such as `cameraImage.planes[0].bytes[10]`, outrside the loop, for example as the 1st line code in your function. then see whether it still errors

Comment: Related: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89584 seems to be problem of dart.

Comment: This seems to be a bug. The index on the error thrown is still within range: `RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 345600: 10`

Comment: Yeap that is bug I reported :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved via [bugfix in dart compiler](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89584). It is currently available in Flutter master channel.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `enable_isolate_groups` flag to `true`

Comment: Could you provide more details on how that flag solves the issue?